# How to replace all \n with space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I want to replace all `\n` with  from the value of a textarea . How can I do that?

I want something like this:

```
$('textarea').val().replace('/\n+/',"");
```

---

Actually here is current value:

```
var TextareaValue = "this
                     is
                     a
                     test";
```

Now I want this:

```
var NewTextareaValue = "this is a test";
```

Comment: `NewTextareaValue  = TextareaValue.replace(/\n+/g, " ");`

Comment: You were very close. The `g` regexp modifier tells it to replace all matches instead of just the first.

Comment: @Barmar I see ... tnx